# PHP - Simple table

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I display my code output in a table like this?

[image: Screenshot of a table with a single column of data]

I want to display the label and value of `$attribute` and `$attribute_label` in a table format, not as a list.

I am very new to PHP and couldn't figure out how to do this. I'm hoping that someone could help me with my problem.

```
// Build the html string with the label followed by a clickable list of terms.
// Updated for WC3.0 to use getters instead of directly accessing property.
$html .= wp_get_object_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, '<li>' . $attribute_label . ': ' , ', ', '</li>' );
```

My Code so far:

```
function so_39394127_attributes_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $product;

    if( ! is_object( $product ) || ! $product->has_attributes() ){
        return;
    }

    // parse the shortcode attributes
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'attributes' => array_keys( $product->get_attributes() ), // by default show all attributes
    ), $atts );

    // is pass an attributes param, turn into array
    if( is_string( $args['attributes'] ) ){
        $args['attributes'] = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|' , $args['attributes'] ) );
    }

    // start with a null string because shortcodes need to return not echo a value
    $html = '';

    if( ! empty( $args['attributes'] ) ){

        foreach ( $args['attributes'] as $attribute ) {

            // get the WC-standard attribute taxonomy name
            $taxonomy = strpos( $attribute, 'pa_' ) === false ? wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute ) : $attribute;

            if( taxonomy_is_product_attribute( $taxonomy ) ){

                // Get the attribute label.
                $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );

                // Build the html string with the label followed by a clickable list of terms.
                // Updated for WC3.0 to use getters instead of directly accessing property.
                $html .= wp_get_object_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, '<li>' . $attribute_label . ': ' , ', ', '</li>' ); 
            }

        }

        // if we have anything to display, wrap it in a <ul> for proper markup
        // OR: delete these lines if you only wish to return the <li> elements
        if( $html ){
            $html = '<ul class="product-attributes">' . $html . '</ul>';
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'display_attributes', 'so_39394127_attributes_shortcode' );
```

Comment: If you want to output a table, you might want to read up on [html tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Comment: hello, i tried this but it wont work out for me since i have no idea how to properly replace `<li> with <table>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to replace:

- `ul` by `table`
- `li` by `tr` and `td`

So you should replace this:

```php
// Build the html string with the label followed by a clickable list of terms.
// Updated for WC3.0 to use getters instead of directly accessing property.
$html .= wp_get_object_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, '<li>' . 
         $attribute_label . ': ' , ', ', '</li>' );
```

By:

```php
$html .= wp_get_object_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, '<tr><td>' . 
        $attribute_label . '</td><td>' , '</td><td>' , '</td></tr>' );
```

And for the `ul`:

```php
$html = '<ul class="product-attributes">' . $html . '</ul>';
```

By:

```php
$html = '<table class="product-attributes">' . $html . '</table>';
```